# Primefaces LazyDataModel and filters

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

Sorry for my english. I have `TireDTO` class:

```java
public class TireDTO {
    public int fromPrice;
    public int toPrice;

    //get and set
}
```

And a form:

```html
<h:inputText id="fromPrice" value="#{tireMB.tireDTO.fromPrice}"/>
<h:inputText id="toPrice" value="#{tireMB.tireDTO.toPrice}"/>
```

I want to use the form with primefaces dataTable and `LazyDataModel` for pagination.

Can I send `TireDTO` instead of `Map<String, Object> filters`?

### Updated

I tried in `TireMB`:

```java
@PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        // +getter , setter
        lazyModel = new LazyDataModel<Site>(){

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public List<Site> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,
                                         SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {

                return getDao().getResultList(getTireDTO(), first, pageSize);
            }
        };

        lazyModel.setRowCount(20);
    }
```

Maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: Have you tried to do it? If no, why not?

Comment: Yes. I tried. I updated the post. But maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: Better... better... different maybe... But this is not a bad solution in my opinion. I made it completely generic and instead of an object, I pass in an additional map that I combine with the map from the load method and via the JPA criteria api have a fully dynamical and flexible way of using filtering IN the datatable and additional filters ('advanced') and even request parameters (so filters become bookmarkable)

Comment: If you explicitly expose `LazyDataModel<T>` by declaring it inside a method or an instance member of the managed bean in question, it is actually not lazy even though it's loaded lazily as you are likely to believe. Lazy means lazy. It should happen only when it is explicitly requested and it should be synchronized tightly with the amount of info which is explicitly requested - paging, sorting, ordering etc. Otherwise, loading should always differ. No explicit action needs to be taken - declaring it somewhere and then using it (no matter the showcase examples demonstrate it in a different way)

Comment: @Tiny: There is no problem in the `LazyDataModel<T>` itself not being lazy. Since the load method gets called each time you page/filter/sort/.. you get new data, tightly coupled to what is requested. It works for me to, although I do it a little differently.

Comment: @Tiny, Primefaces does not offer other solution. How do you in that case?

Comment: @Kukeltje, Can you show an example? In answer to the question, If you do not mind. Thanks.

Comment: Who said PrimeFaces does not offer a solution? Me? No I did not say anything like that. I merely said you should **not** be explicit in creating an instance of `LazyDataModel<T>` (and yes do not get me wrong. Needless to say that It may be needed in (very) special use-cases but that's a story apart - that's all about a different story). In case of `<p:dataTable lazy="true">`, you should always be using as for an example `<p:dataTable var="row" value="#{bean}"/>` (implicitly) and not `<p:dataTable var="row" value="#{bean.list}"/>` or alike (explicitly). And finally, it is my personnel opinion.

Comment: @Tiny, I did not understand you. Why do you use a bean as value  `<p:dataTable var="row" value="#{bean}"/>` ? The bean needs to extends LazyDataModel<T>. Or what do you mean?

Comment: Declare a managed bean of your choice such as `public class ClassName extends LazyDataModel<T> {...}`, override one of the overloaded methods `load()` and then use `<p:dataTable var="row" value="#{className}"/>`. There is no "*Why*". It is the right principle of being *lazy* in the context of PrimeFaces (implicit) - just that you should not hold an instance of `LazyDataModel<T>` somewhere unnecessarily - it should happen implicitly.

Comment: @Tiny, But I can not to use method` load(int first, int pageSize,TireDTO tireDTO)`. This solution is the same that I suggested.  I do not see that this solution is better than mine.